# Visual Code Editor refactoring task before and after paste

Tags: refactoring, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have the following example code in Visual Studio Code:

```
expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Sand Floor');
expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Wash Car');
expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Wax Car');
expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Paint Fence');
```

I want to refactor it quickly like this:

```
it('',()=>{
    expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Sand Floor');
});
it('',()=>{
    expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Wash Car');
});
it('',()=>{
    expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Wax Car');
});
it('',()=>{
    expect(Miyagi.ApplyTraining).toHaveBeenCalledWith(danielSan, 'Paint Fence');
});
```

Is there a way of highlighting a block and specifying a "before" and "after" each-line paste option?

Obviously I can write my own refactor tool outside of this editor but I thought I'd ask the community first!

Answer (score 0):

**Okay so you actually can do this pretty quickly with shortcuts...!!**

e.g. Highlight `"expect"` on the first line and then press ***[CTRL+D]*** repeatedly until all `"expects"` are highlighted and then press ***[home]*** (you should have a cursor in front of each line flashing).

Now type the `"it('',()=>{"` and press ***[return]***.

Press ***[END]*** and then ***[return]***.  Finally type the last part `"});"`

> Here's a few other tips:

**I commonly use these helpful shortcuts too (saves you having to highlight the entire line):**

**[Alt]+[Up or Down]** moves a line up/down.

**[Shift]+[Alt]+[Up]** copies the line your on to the line above.

**[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[k]** removes the line your on.